# PUBNUB - fallback mechanism for messages to mobile devices

Tags: push-notification, pubnub

Taken from PubNub's website:

PubNub Offline Mobile Push -- PubNub also provides a fallback mechanism for messages to mobile devices for when the mobile app is not running (or in the background).  PubNub can fall back to a mobile “push notification”, ensuring the mobile end-user is notified even when the phone is in their pocket.  As soon as the app is launched, the app will begin using PubNub’s Real-Time network again.

**My question is:
If we publish a message and the designated client is offline, Does PubNub "translates" the message to a push notification automatically or should we handle it by our own?
(The structure & parameters of a regular message and a push notification is very different)**

Comment: from pubnub's support we can understand there is no such automation: Q: How does PubNub decide whether to publish an in-app message and when to send a push notification?

A: All messages published on an APNS-enabled key are sent over both PubNub and APNS.  If the application is active, the PubNub subscribe will receive the message.  If the application is inactive, the message will be received as a push notification via APNS.

Comment: My first question is what is your use case? In other words, is the publisher supposed to know if the subscriber is actively listening or is the publisher blindly sending messages and whoever happens to be listening gets the realtime message? Or, is this a 1 to 1 or exclusive group chat where the participants can or should be aware of who is present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PubNub Mobile Push Fallback

**PubNub's Mobile Push** add-on feature allows you to automatically receive messages in the background or while the app is not running.  The message delivery is **automatically** delivered only as a fallback option.  When the app is running the messages will be delivered to the client mobile app via PubNub's Global Realtime Network Data Streams Service.

### When does APN Activate

PubNub will write messages over APNs with appropriate `{ "apn" : ... }` field defined in the message payload.  While the app is in the background or not running, the message is received on the mobile device.  If the app is already running in the foreground, then the messages are ignored by the client.  This way you can be sure the message is delivered to the even if the app isn't running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let's see if we understand correctly: if the server publish a message with some information including images links and some other data (more than 256 bytes long), and the client is currently offline, PubNub will replace the original published message with an APN message that satisfies the rules of APN message (less than 256 bytes) and include  all relevant parameters of APN message, i.e. current 'badge' count? or should the server publish both and PubNum will use the relevant one? (original if client is online, APN else)?

Comment: You need to include your "fallback" payload via `{"apn": ...here... }` which will be delivered via APN and your `"apn"` field must follow the max payload of 256 bytes required by Apple's network.  However if you are looking for a guaranteed message storage, check out: **[PubNub History for Realtime Data Management to Store & Playback Messages](http://www.pubnub.com/how-it-works/storage-and-playback/).**

Comment: @PubNub So if I understand it, I have to put my custom data in both message payload and inside "apn". Should I have to do like this? https://gist.github.com/samnang/16f60aaf032aa02a7ed0

Either way, I receive the message, I will can get the data?

Comment: @PubNub When I tested, it looks like the limited size 265 is for entire message payload, not just for inside "aps" key. What I hope I publish a large message payload(> 265) that has data inside "aps" (< 256), so when the message went out, then Pubnub would split and take only "aps" part sent to apple, so it will not over the limit from apple, and other clients could receive both push notification and entire large message if they are active.

Comment: @Samnang Apple APN will not allow greater than 256 bytes. However PubNub allows 32,000 bytes for the core message.  However if you include an `"apn"` in the PubNub payload dictionary, you must ensure the `"apn"` value is less than 256 bytes.

Comment: "pn_apns" and "pn_gcm" work. Then place the 'aps' inside. A sample payload is in http://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/android/overview/mobile-gateway.html#_google_cloud_messaging_with_mobile_push_gateway. Another ex. http://www.pubnub.com/community/discussion/61/encryption-for-apns-gcm-wms-with-pubnub